# qsort not working - messing up array completely

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

So, I have a struct, consisting of 3 integers. This struct represents one "row" of my "table". Table is basically array of rows, called "v" Because of the task I have, I need to use this format instead of for example 2d array and these things. For now, I need to "lexicographically sort my rows" according to x,y and z. The problem is with the qsort function - it somehow messes up my whole array "v" that becomes useless. I don`t now what is the reason for it. The compare function compares the rows according to x, than according to y and than z (normal lexicographical sorting I think). Function printing just prints the table.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct row {
    int x, y, z;
}; 
int compar(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    if(((row*)p1)->x < ((row*)p2)->x){
        return -1;
    }   
    if(((row*)p1)->x = ((row*)p2)->x){
        if(((row*)p1)->y < ((row*)p2)->y){
            return -1;
        }    
        if(((row*)p1)->y = ((row*)p2)->y){
            if(((row*)p1)->z < ((row*)p2)->z){
                return -1;
            }
            if(((row*)p1)->z = ((row*)p2)->z){
                return 0;
            }
            if(((row*)p1)->z > ((row*)p2)->z){
                return 1;
            }
        }     
        if(((row*)p1)->y > ((row*)p2)->y){
            return 1;
        }
    }    
    if(((row*)p1)->x > ((row*)p2)->x){
        return 1;
    }
}

void printing(row v[], int p){
    cout << "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        cout << v[i].x << " " << v[i].y<< ' ' << v[i].z << endl;
    }
    cout << "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << endl;
}
int main(void){
    int numOfRows;
    cin >> numOfRows; //format of input needs this
    row  v[numOfRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {    
        cin >> v[i].x >> v[i].y  >> v[i].z;  
    }
    qsort(v,numOfRows,sizeof(row),compar);
    printing(v,numOfRows);
}
```

now I am posting inputs with outputs and you can clearly see, that some rows were duplicated in sorting process and some of them are missing completely.

```
3
1 2 3
1 4 5
1 2 4
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 4
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

next input and output is:

```
4
100 100 100
100 100 100
100 99 99
99 99 100
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
99 99 99
99 99 99
99 99 99
99 99 100
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

How it should apparently look instead is for example:

```
3
1 2 3
1 4 5
1 2 4
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 4 5
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This would be the correct output of my qsort. Any help would be gladly appreciated, as I have absolutely no idea why this happens. I have been trying to solve this for the whole afternoon and I am out of ideas. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd make new vars at the top of your `compar` function like `row *row1 = (row *)p1;`, so you don't have to cast so often.

Comment: Why do you use `qsort` in the first place?

Comment: It seems like your comparison function is too complicated, I don't think there are so many possible different conditions. Also, please don't tag with [tag:c] because solutions will be different in c and you are obviously using c++.

Comment: yeah, that is true, my bad, however, I think that the algorithm is fairly simple and correct in my implementation and shouldnot afect the disappearing rows, it is just a normal lexicographical compare: if p1.x equals p2.x try y, if it equals too, try z, If something doesn` t equal, terurn which one is "smaller"

Comment: You have a single = in the second comparison. That will change the coordinates rather than comparing them.

Comment: OH NO! It seems that you are right! This is such an awful mistake! I can`t believe, that I spent hours debugging without noticing this. Thank you, very much

Answer (score 2):

A lot of your comparisons have `=` instead of `==`, and that will lead to values being copied to places where they shouldn't be. If you set the warning level on your compiler high enough it should warn you about this.

Answer (score 1):

The function `compar` does not have a return value at the end. It leads to undefined behavior.

You can simplify it to:

```
int compar(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
   row const* row1 = (row const*)p1;
   row const* row2 = (row const*)p2;

   if ( row1->x != row2->x )
   {
      return (row1->x - row2->x);
   }

   if ( row1->y != row2->y )
   {
      return (row1->y - row2->y);
   }

   return (row1->z - row2->z);
}
```